# error of import mayavi.mlab

Tags: python, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

I would like to use mlab in mayavi.
Thus I install mayavi through anaconda in may python

And then I can import mayavi but I can't import mayavi.mlab
when I was type mayavi.mlab the error messages came out like this !

```
>>> import mayavi.mlab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\FUS\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mayavi\mlab.py", line 27, in <module>
    from mayavi.tools.camera import view, roll, yaw, pitch, move
  File "C:\Users\FUS\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\camera.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .engine_manager import get_engine
  File "C:\Users\FUS\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mayavi\tools\engine_manager.py", line 14, in <module>
    from mayavi.core.engine import Engine
  File "C:\Users\FUS\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mayavi\core\engine.py", line 28, in <module>
    from mayavi.core.base import Base
  File "C:\Users\FUS\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\mayavi\core\base.py", line 19, in <module>
    from tvtk.pyface.tvtk_scene import TVTKScene
  File "C:\Users\FUS\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tvtk\pyface\tvtk_scene.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tvtk.pyface import light_manager
  File "C:\Users\FUS\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tvtk\pyface\light_manager.py", line 130, in <module>
    class CameraLight(HasTraits):
  File "C:\Users\FUS\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tvtk\pyface\light_manager.py", line 146, in CameraLight
    source = Instance(tvtk.Light, ())
  File "C:\Users\FUS\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tvtk\tvtk_classes.zip\tvtk_classes\tvtk_helper.py", line 225, in <lambda>
  File "C:\Users\FUS\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tvtk\tvtk_classes.zip\tvtk_classes\tvtk_helper.py", line 36, in get_class
  File "C:\Users\FUS\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tvtk\tvtk_classes.zip\tvtk_classes\tvtk_helper.py", line 28, in get_module
  File "C:\Users\FUS\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tvtk\tvtk_classes.zip\tvtk_classes\light.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\FUS\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\tvtk\array_handler.py", line 28, in <module>
    from tvtk.array_ext import set_id_type_array
ImportError: cannot import name set_id_type_array
```

Thus I very appreciate If you give me some solution of this problem's

Thanks